# physicsBody not working when initialized in another class?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

For some reason my physicsBody for my main player isn't actually working in the scene.
In the scene I initialize my player

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    Eskimo *runner = [[Eskimo alloc]init];
    runner.position = CGPointMake(100, 300);
    [self addChild:runner];


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -3); // 0, -2

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    [runner performRun];
    }
return self;
}
```

Here is the init for my Eskimo class:

```
-(id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {

    self.name = @"runner";

    self.physicsBody = ((Eskimo*)[[Physics alloc]initPhys:self.name :CGSizeMake(60, 60)]).physicsBody;

}

return self;
}
```

Here is part of the init for my physics class:

```
-(instancetype)initPhys:(NSString*)string :(CGSize)size{
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.type = string;

    if ([self.type isEqualToString:@"runner"]) {
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:size];
        self.physicsBody.restitution = 0.3;
        self.physicsBody.mass = 1;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = runnerCategory;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = monsterCategory;
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = groundCategory|monsterCategory;

    }
}

return self;


}
```

I outputted the restitution of my runner in the scene class just to see if the physicsBody was there and it came out properly.  However, even though I set a gravity vector, the runner isnt affected by it, or any forces that I apply to it.  I have no idea why because it was working before when I had the physicsBody stuff in the Eskimo class itself, without the Physics class. Is there something I'm missing here? Can you not equate physicsBodies like what I did in the Eskimo class?

Comment: some things don't add up. For one, you assign the physicsBody to both Physics class and the Eskimo class. If both Eskimo and Physics are subclasses of SK*Node that's a problem. Furthermore you cast Physics to Eskimo - not that it matters in this case but it is illegal to cast a base class to a subclass (?).

Comment: Eskimo and Physics are both subclasses of SKNode. How is that a problem though? I am just equating two nodes' physics bodies together.

Comment: And the physics class initializes the physics for other objects I have in my game, I just left those parts out as the result is the same as this one.

Comment: problem is that the same physicsBody must not be assigned to two or more nodes. Both eskimo and physics class use the same body, this won't work. You probably shouldn't even create a physics class, you only need a method that returns a skphysicsbody.